# PERL script to interpret GCODE

Tags: perl, replace

I've been working on a PERL script that I received from yet another person on a 3D-printing forum.

What it does is find a line that looks like this:
G1 F1800.000 E0.15799
into a line like this:
M104 S0

And this line:
G1 E5.00000 F1800.000
into this:
M104 S100

The script *should* be working, however, running it either through command line, nor through the slicing (Slic3r) software, doesn't yield any results. I am also able to use a python script, however, I don't know how to script with python at all.

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -i.before_postproc
#
# Author  : Guy Poizat
# Version : 1.2
# Copyright : none.
#
# Change from previous version : added handling of slic3r's retraction speed setting,
#  so that this script is not disrupted by a setting change.

use strict;
use warnings;

# what will replace a retraction line with : gcode to cut the laser power off.
my $powerOffLine = "M104 S0\n";

# what will replace an "unretraction" line with : gcode to switch the laser power on.
my $powerOnLine = "M104 S100\n";

# Extract the speed setting from slic3r's environment variables (or use the default 30mm/s).
#  Unit is millimeters per minute in gcode, millimeters per second in slic3r configuration.
my $defaultRetractSpeed = 1800;
my $envRetractSpeed = $ENV{"SLIC3R_RETRACT_SPEED"};
my $retractSpeed = defined( $envRetractSpeed ) ? $envRetractSpeed * 60 : $defaultRetractSpeed;

# pattern of a retraction line - would make the filament back-off before a non printing move
#  on a FDM 3d printer, to avoid ooze.
my $retractLine = "G1 F$retractSpeed.* E";

# pattern of an unretraction line - would make the filament forward back to its position before starting extruding again.
my $unretractLine = "G1 E.* F$retractSpeed";

# read stdin and any/all files passed as parameters one line at a time
while (< > ) {
    if (/$retractLine/) {
        # if we found a retraction line, replace it with laser power off
        print "$powerOffLine";
    }
    else {
        # nothing to change, print line as-is
        print or die $!;
    }

    if (/$unretractLine/) {
        # if we have an un-retraction line, append laser power on right after it
        print "$powerOnLine";
    }
}
```

The script is called by Slic3r, a gcode generator for 3D-printing. It then changes a few lines of code throughout the whole file to make it work correctly with a lasercutter I built myself.

I will supply a gcode example file so one can see the code I am trying to change.

Really can't find out what the problem is! It should run just fine.
Thanks for your time, you will help out a lot of people if this script is made working.
- Marinus

An example piece of GCODE can be found here:

```
G21 ; set units to millimeters
M104 S0 (turns off laser)
G21
G28 X0 Y0 Z0
G91
G1 Z+6 F4000 (Sends Z to focal length)
G90
G92 X0 Y0 Z0 E0 (sets logical zero)
M400
M104 S100 (turns on laser)
G90 ; use absolute coordinates
G92 E0
M82 ; use absolute distances for extrusion
M204 S2200
G1 Z0.100 F14400.000
G1 F1800.000 E-5.00000
G92 E0
G1 X25.383 Y62.928 F14400.000
G1 E5.00000 F1800.000
G1 X24.893 Y61.890 E5.00162 F480.000
G1 X24.552 Y60.811 E5.00322
G1 X24.475 Y59.685 E5.00482
G1 X29.714 Y62.560 E5.15186
G1 X27.126 Y62.850 E5.15554
G1 X25.398 Y62.927 E5.15799
G1 F1800.000 E0.15799
G92 E0
G1 X45.931 Y77.187 F14400.000
G1 E5.00000 F1800.000
G1 X45.115 Y81.009 E5.00553 F480.000
G1 X44.514 Y85.098 E5.01138
G1 X36.645 Y81.972 E5.08052
G1 X39.298 Y81.849 E5.08428
G1 X41.096 Y80.860 E5.08718
G1 X45.919 Y77.196 E5.09575
G1 F1800.000 E0.09575
G92 E0
G1 X35.177 Y48.889 F14400.000
G1 E5.00000 F1800.000
G1 X35.280 Y48.648 E5.00037 F480.000
G1 X35.441 Y48.437 E5.00075
G1 X35.714 Y48.389 E5.00114
G1 X38.692 Y48.215 E5.00536
G1 X40.179 Y47.884 E5.00751
G1 X40.964 Y47.413 E5.00881
G1 X41.626 Y46.859 E5.01003
```

Comment: Please show how you are invoking the script when you test manually. It is designed to take input on STDIN, so it can sit in command line pipe e.g. `cat input.txt | script.pl > output.txt`

Comment: Hi Neil, I have tested like this: `/Users/marinusdebeer/Documents/lasercuts/slicerscript_laser1.pl /Users/marinusdebeer/Documents/lasercuts/paaseiland.gcode` when I run the script as you suggested, it outputs an empty file, I used: `cat /Users/marinusdebeer/Documents/lasercuts/paaseiland.gcode | /Users/marinusdebeer/Documents/lasercuts/slicerscript_laser1.pl > /Users/marinusdebeer/Documents/lasercuts/paaseilandtest.gcode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line here is what's wrong:

```
# read stdin and any/all files passed as parameters one line at a time
while (< > ) {
```

Because it doesn't do what the comment says it does.

Change it to:

```
while ( <STDIN> ) {
```

(assuming you want to read from STDIN - if you want to read filenames from the command line, you'll need to open them explicitly)

Comment: Hey thanks, I replied to your last statement, `<>` also works instead of `<STDIN>` it's working miracles. I am sure going to share this with the lasercutting communities as this simple piece of code will open up a whole new world of functionality to them :)

Comment: Yes, it does. But part of the reason for the problem was using `<>` because it's only a single character different from `< >`. That's just generally bad coding style - `<STDIN>` is entirely clearly what it's doing, and won't break mysteriously if you typo. (As you did).

Answer (score 1):

Consider what B::Deparse says

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -le " while(< >){ print } "
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
use File::Glob ();
while (defined($_ = < >)) {
    print $_;
}
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Deparse -le " while(<>){ print } "
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

`<>` and `< >` are not the same, the first is `<ARGV>`  and the second is `glob(" ")`

Comment: Hey, I *think* I understand this, but it is too complicated for me. Deparse is so that you get the code back as PERL interprets it, right? I tried implementing it in my code, but I get all kinds of syntax errors.

Comment: Deparse is perl untanging some of the idioms. Such as replacing 'unless' with 'if not' etc. It's useful troubleshooting to see what your code is actually doing. 
Having syntax errors is an important thing to look at first though. But as pointed out - you're using `<>` and `< >` without understanding that they're different.

Comment: This is very useful, I have replaced the `< >` with `<>` and it works! Thanks a lot, I have been wondering what could be wrong for so long. The only strange thing that it does, is it replaces the line in the first case, but adds a line in the second case instead of replacing it. Still will try to fix that!